# Child and parent object

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I would like to know if this is possible or not:

I want to create an object and attach to it another object.

```
OBJECT A
    Child 1
    Child 2
OBJECT B
    Child 3
    Child 4
    Child 5
        Child 6
            Child 7
```

is this possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by "attach it to another object"?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The right answer is: What are you trying to do that you think this will solve? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: We can imagine a really simple problem. I have an object : a car. I'm going to create two of them, a red one and a blue one. After that, I'm going to create 8 tires (4 for each car) with différents weights. I want to know at the end the weight of the 4 tires for the blue car and the red car.

Comment: Then you want to use *attributes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow your example:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, tire_size = 1):
        self.tires = [Tire(tire_size) for _ in range(4)]

class Tire(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.weight = 2.25 * size
```

Now you can make a car and query the tire weights:

```
>>> red = Car(1)
>>> red.tires
[<Tire object at 0x7fe08ac7d890>, <Tire object at 0x7fe08ac7d9d0>, <Tire object at 0x7fe08ac7d7d0>, <Tire object at 0x7fe08ac7d950>]
>>> red.tires[0]
<Tire object at 0x7fe08ac7d890>
>>> red.tires[0].weight
2.25
```

You can change the structure as needed, as a better way (if all the tires are the same) is to just specify `tire` and `num_tires`:

```
>>> class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, tire):
        self.tire = tire
        self.num_tires = 4
>>> blue = Car(Tire(2))
>>> blue.tire.weight
4.5
>>> blue.num_tires
4
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about object oriented terms, yes you can,you dont explain clearly what you want to do, but the 2 things that come to my mind if you are talking about OOP are:

- If you are talking about inheritance you can make child objects extend parent objects when you create your child class:  class child(parent):
- If you are talking about object composition, you just make child object an isntance variable of parent object and pass it as a constructor variable

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

In this scenario an object can be a person without being an employee, however to be an employee they must be a person. Therefor the person class is a parent to the employee

Here's the link to an article that really helped me understand inheritance:
http://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.firstname = first
        self.lastname = last

    def Name(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname

class Employee(Person):

    def __init__(self, first, last, staffnum):
        Person.__init__(self,first, last)
        self.staffnumber = staffnum

    def GetEmployee(self):
        return self.Name() + ", " +  self.staffnumber

x = Person("Marge", "Simpson")
y = Employee("Homer", "Simpson", "1007")

print(x.Name())
print(y.GetEmployee())
```